# Consume a REST API in codeigniter controller

Tags: rest, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder, codeigniter-restapi

I have create a REST API and want to consume my own created API in codeigniter controller.

My created REST API
controller(example.php)

```
   class Example extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct() { 
    parent::__construct();        
    $this->load->model('user');
   }

     public function user_fetch_post() {
    //returns all rows if the id parameter doesn't exist,
    //otherwise single row will be returned
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $users = $this->user->getRows($id);

    //check if the user data exists
    if(!empty($users)){
        //set the response and exit
        $this->response($users, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        //set the response and exit
        $this->response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'No user were found.'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    }
```

model(user.php)

```
    function getRows($id = ""){
    if(!empty($id)){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }else{
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    }
```

Here i want to call my created api(from example.php)for fetch record in welcome.php controller with basic authentication(uname-admin,pwd-1234)

my controller welcome.php

```
public function index()
{
}
```

Can anybody help to me that how to call my api in controller welcome.php with basic authentication.

Comment: Can u show me your rest api class  full code

Comment: now i updated my post ,please check above.

Answer (score 0):

Using CURL you can consume any API/network call.

```
<?php
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:password") // place your auth details here
    );
    $payload = array(
        'id' => 1,
    );

    $process = curl_init($host); //your API url
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);

    //finally print your API response
    print_r($return);
?>
```

But why are you calling your own API this way? You can simply call your API model and perform your operations

Comment: I have use your code as below             $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("admin:1234") 
    );
    $payload = array(
        'id' => 1,
    );
  
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin' . ":" . '1234');
    but it shows an error   "Invalid API key "  my api key is admin@123 , how i put api key here.

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your curl options

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'APIKEY: admin@123',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
```

also update

```
$config['rest_key_name'] = 'APIKEY';
```

in rest.php file inside config folder of your codeigniter settings. By default it is 'X-API-KEY'

This may help to somebody else looking for a solution, if OP has resolved it himself/herself.